# How do you change the URL of a page without invalidating Facebook likes/object relationships?

Tags: facebook, permalinks

Here's what we're trying to do.

We use WordPress.

We use the category name in our permalinks. Here's a non-working example:

mydomainname.com/**old-category**/my-post-slug

We have like buttons and we're using the comment widget. Both reference this permalink for the purposes of uniquely identifying this URL to Facebook. My understanding is that both the comments and like counts are bound via this URL.

Now, consider this case. We want to rename "Old Category" to "New Category." Doing so affects the following change in URL:

mydomainname.com/**new-category**/my-post-slug

This is a problem because now like counts and comments, which were bound to the original URL are gone.

The best solution I can imagine doesn't use the page's actual URL, but instead uses something even more permanent than the permalink, e.g., the unique ID of the post:

mydomainname.com/?p=12345

The problem with this, I'm told, is that the actual URL has SEO value because it contains the category name and the post title. For this reason, and also because we have thousands of posts that already have likes and comments associated with their actual URLs, switching all of our URLs to some other new, SEO-valueless URL is not an option.

The next best solution I can imagine is to store the initial permalink somewhere outside of the standard database field. Using custom overrides, we then make use of this more permanent version of the permalink for associating the page with likes and comments. We assumed then that if we changed the URL of the page, as described above, we could continue to use the old permalink for links and comments, and continue on joyfully.

But apparently we were wrong about this, too.

When I Lint my URL with the Facebook debugger I get this error:

> Circular Redirect: Circular redirect path detected (see Redirect Path section for details).
>
> Error Scraping Redirect: Bad Response Code (redirect)

The error reads:

> original: mydomainname.com/new-category/my-post-slug
>
> og:url: mydomainname.com/old-category/my-post-slug
>
> 301: mydomainname.com/new-category/my-post-slug

While I understand why Facebook is doing this (attempting to ensure that the URL that gets published matches the content displayed for that URL in news stories and elsewhere on Facebook), it's a roadblock around which we have no path.

Is there a way to make this work, or is my only option to forfeit existing counts and comments? Seems like a really bad option.

**UPDATE:** It occurs to me now that the "best" option that I proposed above wouldn't work either. Because WordPress always redirects **http://mydomainname.com/?p=12345** to the permalink (e.g., **http://mydomainname.com/new-category/my-post-slug**), using the **?p=12345** URL would put us in exactly the same boat we are in with solution #2: circular redirects do to **og:url** not matching the actual URL of the page. Grrr...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move a URL via 301 redirect and retain the page's Facebook likes and Open Graph information?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o)

Answer (score 0):

I think **canonical URLs** may be what you're looking for.